# How to solve this error in my local machine?

Tags: api, jmeter

```
Could not create script recorder - see log for details: >> keytool error: java.secuirity.KeyStoreException: jks not found <<
Command failed, code: 1
'keytool -genkeypair - alias : root_ca:-dname "CN= _JMeter Root for CA for recording (INSTALL ONLY IF IT S YOURS ), OU= Username: ujala , C=IN" -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserver .jks -storepass {redacted}-keypass {redacted}-validity 7 - ext bc:c'
```

How to solve this error during the recording controller in JMeter???

Answer (score 0):

If you properly installed JMeter and Java you should not see error like this, at least I have never faced anything similar.

The fact that [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html) application cannot detect `jks` keystore type which is the [default type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getDefaultType()) indicates that something is wrong with your Java installation so I would recommend reinstalling [JDK](https://openjdk.org/) from scratch.

My expectation is that it should resolve your issue. If it doesn't - check whether you (or somebody else) amended any default [Test Script Recorder certificate configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert). If the values differ from defaults - try reverting them (or even reinstalling JMeter)

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't need to think about proxies and certificates